# Optimize SQL Query (WordPress)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, query-optimization

1.the first table -> wp_fv_enteries

[wp_fv_enteries table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNMOw.png)

this table has more than 3000 records in it.

2.the second table -> wp_fv_entry_meta

[wp_fv_enteries_meta table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qido.png)

this table has more than 21000 records in it

** the query **

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_fv_enteries as entry
INNER JOIN wp_fv_entry_meta as e1 ON (entry.id = e1.data_id AND e1.meta_key = 'name')
INNER JOIN wp_fv_entry_meta as e2 ON (entry.id = e2.data_id AND e2.meta_key = 'name' ) 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND 
(
 (e1.meta_key = 'name' AND e1.meta_value = 'Elliot Ross')
  OR 
 (e2.meta_key = 'name' AND e2.meta_value = 'Andy Chapman')  
) 
and form_plugin='elementor'
and form_id='398ee45' 
and DATE_FORMAT(captured,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')) >= '2020-01-01' 
and DATE_FORMAT(captured,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')) <= '2020-12-31'
order by captured desc 
limit 20
```

the query working but taking really really long time to execute.
the more filters i add like in inner join the longer it takes to execute.
any optimization I could make so that it runs fast.

the output this query gives me(but taking a long time to execute)

[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpZTc.png)

Thanks.

Comment: What is going on with `GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')` ?

Comment: (1) The conditions by `meta_key` in ON clause is excess, remove. (2) Simplify the conditions by `captured`, use `.. AND captured BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31 23:59:59'`. (3) Create proper indices.

Comment: hi @TimBiegeleisen via GET_FORMAT I am trying to get "captured" column in JIS format.

Comment: *via GET_FORMAT I am trying to get "captured" column in JIS format.* This makes no sense, this is default date format in MySQL. By fact this construction simply removes timepart from a value. And does not allow to use index.

Comment: hi @Akina thanks for your response i will try it out. and about GET_FORMAT visit here [link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-get_format-function.php)

Comment: *and about GET_FORMAT visit here link* NEVER refer to third-party documents while speaking about std. entities. ALWAYS provide the links to the official Reference manual strictly, like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format

Comment: @Akina thanks for your advice I will keep this in my mind next time :)

Comment: Convert your Inner joins to Left Joins and try

Comment: Functions cannot use indexes, so on an indexed column, a range query will typically be faster. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

That table comes from the [Form Vibes](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/form-vibes/) plugin. It's defined like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE wp_fv_enteries (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    form_plugin VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    form_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    captured VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    captured_gmt VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    url TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    user_agent TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    fv_status VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'undefined' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
)  COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Gosh, it's a bad table definition.  No primary key, no indexes on anything except the `id` (which should be the primary key anyhow), using VARCHAR(50) rather than DATETIME for datestamp columns. Even its name is misspelled (they want "entries"; "enteries" sounds like it has to do with gastrointestinal medicine).

You can fix some of that like so.

```sql
ALTER TABLE wp_fv_enteries 
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
   DROP KEY id,
   ADD KEY id_plugin_captured (form_id, form_plugin, captured);
```

That creates a covering index for your query.

By similar logic, the `wp_fv_entry_meta` table needs some fixing up to be efficient. Ask the plugin developer to read about clustered indexing and matching the data types used in ON conditions. `entry.id = e1.data_id` compares an INT with a VARCHAR(50). That is slow.

The function call [`GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format) happens to return `'%Y-%m-%d'`. That's the same as MySQL's default format for dates, so you don't need it.

Also, you can use `captured < '2020-12-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` in place of what you have, so you get rows dated `2020-12-31` up until midnight on the next day. Refactor this

```sql
and DATE_FORMAT(captured,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')) >= '2020-01-01' 
and DATE_FORMAT(captured,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'JIS')) <= '2020-12-31'
```

to

```sql
and captured >= '2020-01-01' 
and captured <  '2020-12-31' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If the contents of that `captured` column are messy rather than just ordinary datetime items, this refactoring might not work. The index will still help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Store the dates in yyyy-mm-dd so you don't need to do all that reformatting (which hurts performance)
- Change the indexes on postmeta according to tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta  (WordPress does not scale well because of using the "EAV" schema pattern.  That link gives some kludges that will help.)
- Use `IN()` instead of `OR` for testing for either `name`.
- `INDEX(form_id, form_plugin, captured)`